# Angular 2/4 AoT build: spurious resolution error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I am configuring my Angular 4 app to build using AoT for production, as described in [this post](https://medium.com/@laco0416/aot-compilation-with-webpack-359ac9f4916f) and [GitHub repository](https://github.com/laco0416/ngtools-webpack-example/tree/aot-plugin).

There have been lots of errors in this process, mainly pertaining to `@type`s which I have resolved, but there is one curious error that remains when running `npm run build:prod`:

> ERROR in Could not resolve "./app/src/app.module.ts" from "./app/src/app.module.ts".

I have no idea how to solve this, and Googling yields meager results. Can anyone help me out with what this might mean and how to solve it?

I don't know if it's a `tsconfig.json` error or otherwise. Can anyone help?

Comment: Everything seems to point at AotPlugin - entryModule, and making it relative path, inside - webpack.config.js

Comment: Most AOT errors are spurious.

Comment: Hi @Dylan, that was the issue, thanks for the pointer. I used `path.resolve()` rather than a direct relative path and that solved it.